# create image histogram from 3 different histogram

Tags: opencv, image-processing, histogram

I have a images 3 frames which slight variation in each. Each frame has its own histogram in RGB space. I am trying to form one histogram from the 3 histogram of the original frame. Is it possible to achieve this. Any hint

Comment: you can concatenate three histograms to make a single histogram.

Comment: @baban actually that is what i was thinking and how would i join the the 3 different histogram. My thoughts is to use OR function and join the 3. Why i thought of or is because, since the 3 images are of same width and height, the number of pixel will be same. Now, to keep that same, I felt OR function will not alter anything thing other than conacting it based on its truth table. This is just my idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bin-wise average histogram of the 3 should give you what you're looking for.